# One of the google search results showing in strangely different font. Why?

Tags: css, firefox, google-search, firefox-developer-tools

When searching for "shakespeare davis better call saul", one of the results is shown in different font. The more strange thing is, it is also shown in same different font in Developer Tools.

[image]

And the same thing happens in Firefox too.

[image]

Is there any explanation about this?

Comment: Although off-topic I'm curious as to why this happens as well as I have never seen it before

Comment: Can reproduce on Edge and Chrome. Should be said again though that this *is* offtopic, but I don't really want to close it.

Comment: Try searching for "site: http://www.shakespearedavis.org/wp-content/uploads/formidable". It appears to be something related to that site. (The plot thickens. The semicolon next to the link shows up automatically, I can't get rid of it).

Comment: There has to be an explanation. Please someone explain it! I'm really curious about how come a web site can change the font of the dev tools...

Comment: @Carcigenicate Where do you get the semicolon?

Comment: @RamazanPolat On my computer and phone, it's showing a semicolon next to the "" in my above comment. I didn't put it there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this answer's your question, this is what I found using text to ascii, for    `3 4 03` I got this as the result

`240 157 145 169 240 157 146 134 240 157 146 149 240 157 146 149 240 157 146 134 240 157 146 147 032 240 157 145 170 240 157 146 130 240 157 146 141 240 157 146 141 032 240 157 145 186 240 157 146 130 240 157 146 150 240 157 146 141 032 240 157 145 186 051 032 240 157 145 172 052 032 240 157 145 186 048 051`

Breaking it down, just for the character  the code is `240 157 145 169`
anything less just makes it gibberish.

This is what I get for the text `Better Call Saul S3 E4 S03`

`066 101 116 116 101 114 032 067 097 108 108 032 083 097 117 108 032 083 051 032 069 052 032 083 048 051`

and as expected the code for `B` is jus `066`. What do you make of it?